# How can I allow a user to filter models dynamically and export only certain fields?

Tags: django, django-models

I've been asked to design a way for people to search through multiple models on criteria they enter and allow them to export any number of fields they select.

Example:
User enters "Teacher" as a term for Job Title and "Google" for a Work Site Location but want to export "Employee ID", "First Name", "Last Name", "Date of Birth"

I'm sure this is possible, but I'm at a complete loss for where to start.

My models (for reference) are here:

```
import datetime
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django.utils import timezone


class Classification(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Classification Name')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Classification'
        verbose_name = 'Classification'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Classifications'


class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Name')
    aeries_id = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Aeries ID')
    county_id = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='County ID')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Location'
        verbose_name = 'Location'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Locations'
        ordering = ['name']


class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    current_identity = models.ForeignKey('PersonIdentity', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='Current Identity', related_name='current_identity')
    employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Employee ID')
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Birthdate')
    original_hire_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Original Hire Date')

    def __str__(self):
        if self.current_identity is not None:
            return '{}'.format(str(self.current_identity))
        else:
            return "{}".format(self.employee_id)

    @property
    def current_age(self):
        from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
        difference_in_years = relativedelta(timezone.now().date(), self.birthdate).years
        return difference_in_years

    def primary_assignment(self):
        return self.jobassignment_set.filter(Q(end_date__gte=timezone.now()) | Q(end_date=None)).order_by('priority')[0]

    @property
    def display_name(self):
        if self.current_identity:
            return '{0.first_name} {0.last_name} ({1.employee_id})'.format(self.current_identity, self)
        else:
            return 'Employee ID {0.employee_id}'.format(self)

    @property
    def is_certificated(self):
        assignments = JobAssignment.objects.filter(Q(end_date__gte=timezone.now()) | Q(end_date=None)).filter(
            person=self,
            classification__name__icontains="Certificated"
        )
        return assignments.count() >= 1

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Person'
        verbose_name = 'Person'
        verbose_name_plural = 'People'


class PersonIdentity(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, verbose_name='Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='First Name')
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Middle Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Last Name')
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False, default=datetime.date.today, verbose_name='Start Date')
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='End Date')

    def __str__(self):
        first_name = '' if self.first_name is None else self.first_name
        last_name = '' if self.last_name is None else self.last_name
        if self.middle_name is not None and self.middle_name != '':
            return "{} {}. {} ({})".format(first_name, self.middle_name[0], last_name, self.person.employee_id)
        else:
            return "{} {} ({})".format(first_name, last_name, self.person.employee_id)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        change_identity = False
        if not self.id:
            change_identity = True
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if change_identity:
            self.person.current_identity = self
            self.person.save()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'PersonIdentity'
        verbose_name = 'Person Identity'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Person Identities'
        ordering = ['end_date', 'last_name', 'first_name']


class Contact(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Person')
    email_address = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Primary Email')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Phone Number')
    phone_extension = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Phone Extension')
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Address 1')
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Address 2')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='City')
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='CA', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='State')
    postal = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Postal Code')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.person.current_identity)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Contact'
        verbose_name = 'Contact'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Contacts'


class Department(models.Model):
    department_id = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Department ID')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Department Description')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.description)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Department'
        verbose_name = 'Department'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Departments'


class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Name')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Code')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Job'
        verbose_name = 'Job'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Jobs'


class JobPosition(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Job')
    reports_to = models.ForeignKey('JobPosition', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Reports To')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Name')
    number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Number')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'JobPosition'
        verbose_name = 'Job Position'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Job Positions'


class JobAssignment(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Person')
    position = models.ForeignKey(JobPosition, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Position')
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='School')
    classification = models.ForeignKey(Classification, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Classification')
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Start Date')
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='End Date')
    effective_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Effective Date')
    fte = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='FTE')
    seniority_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Seniority Date')
    last_start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Last Start Date')
    last_pay_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Last Pay Date')
    entry_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Position Entry Date')
    record_number = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Position Record Number')
    pay_group = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Pay Group')
    indicator = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Indicator')
    full_or_part_time = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Full/Part')
    standard_hours_per_week = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Standard Hours per Week')
    pay_status = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Pay Status')
    comp_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=6, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Comp Rate')
    comp_frequency = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Comp Freq')
    hourly_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Hrly Rate')
    daily_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Daily Rt')
    rate_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Rate Code')
    compensation_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=6, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Compensation Rate')
    total_cdays = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='TOTAL_CDAYS')
    teacher_hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Teacher Hours')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.position.name, self.position.number)

    @classmethod
    def current_assignments(cls):
        return cls.objects.filter(Q(end_date__gte=timezone.now()) | Q(end_date=None)).exclude(person__ssn__isnull=True).exclude(person__current_identity__isnull=True).exclude(person__contact__isnull=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'JobAssignment'
        verbose_name = 'Job Assignment'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Job Assignments'
        ordering = ['location__name', 'person__current_identity__last_name', 'person__current_identity__first_name', 'position__name']
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to reimplement graphql. Am I right?

Comment: I've not heard of that, I'll take a look.

Comment: What you state as an example is a start. You need to have a form where people select which fields and values they want to filter on, and what fields they want to export, and process that form to build a query. How complex and flexible is the form depends on your data and on the questions you may want to ask. For instance, you could have dropdowns and checkboxes for selecting fields and values, or you could allow the users to write text where appropriate. If you try to start that and get stuck you may have a more specific question to ask then.

Comment: That said, after commenting I looked up graphql and [it looks interesting](https://gearheart.io/blog/how-to-use-graphql-with-django-with-example/).

Comment: After looking at graphql, it looks super awesome but that will be too much for my users to use. I think I'll start making headway on the suggestion @PauloAlmeida mentioned which is just to build a UI around my idea. Thanks for the help guys :)